# Custom keyboard iOS8 non english characters

Tags: ios8, xcode6, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension, uiinputviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a **burmese language** keyboard for iOS8. And i can not figure out how to let iOS know about the characters. I've my custom keyboard displayed in safari, but when i try to write, it shows as "?" only. I've tried unicodes so far. and don't understand how to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

The Burmese characters are in the Unicode range U+1000 – U+109F   (4096–4255) or in swift "\u{1000}".."\u{109F}"

On my iPad I don't see any characters displayed on this page

[Test For Myanmar support in web browsers](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/myanmar.html)

Are you sure that iOS8 has support for that Unicode range in its fonts ? It is possible that it may have in some fonts but not all.